# Set Blazor WASM Host URL in AppSettings

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I know for a "normal" ASPNET Core app, I can set the URL for it using the `ASPNETCORE_URLS` entry in appsettings (or environment variable).

However, this doesn't seem to work in Blazor WASM, and so far the only option I can see is to overwrite `applicationUrl` in the `launchSettings.json` as part of my build pipeline but that seems messy.

I can't even see anything along the lines of `.UseUrls()` on the `WebAssemblyHostBuilder` that I could make use of with a custom entry in `appsettings.json`.

What's the canonical way to do this? I've not been able to find anything in the docs.

Comment: appsettings is not copied to www root directory where wasm is served from

Comment: Reading the appsettings isn't the issue, I've got that sorted, the issue is how to actually set the URL from that in a Blazor WASM app

Answer (score 0):

REF: [Host and deploy ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

A "normal" ASP.NET Core App comes with Kestrel, a web server.

There are 3 hosting models for Blazor

- Blazor Server
- ASP.NET Core Hosted
- Blazor WASM

The first 2, Blazor Server and ASP.NET Core Hosted have Kestrel, and can be configured like a "normal" app.

Blazor WASM does not come packaged with Kestrel, but does depend on a host whether it is ASP.NET Core hosted, or hosted like a static site on a web server.

The launchSettings.json is simply telling IISEXpress which port to serve the Blazor App on while running / debugging with Visual Studio and is your option for configuring the port locally.

When deploying it, you must configure the server if there is an alternate URL/Port.